# Heroku application receives traffic when website appears in a Google search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a heroku application that is running on free dynos and is connected to the www.teamlink.xyz domain. It seems that every time the website appears in a google search, the application receives traffic, its status changes to UP so it consumes free dyno hours.

Is this behavior normal? Is there something that can be done to avoid it?

Here are the application's logs after a google search...

```
2019-03-14T07:00:03.647454+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143

2019-03-14T10:11:48.458309+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2019-03-14T10:11:48.462336+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2019-03-14T10:11:52.952350+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command bin/rails server -p 16809 -e production
2019-03-14T10:11:58.943903+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-03-14T10:11:58.881149+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2019-03-14T10:11:58.881166+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.2.2 application starting in production
2019-03-14T10:11:58.881168+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run rails server -h for more startup options
2019-03-14T10:11:58.881234+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2019-03-14T10:11:58.881308+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.4.1-p111), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
2019-03-14T10:11:58.881404+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2019-03-14T10:11:58.881467+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2019-03-14T10:11:58.881673+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:16809
2019-03-14T10:11:58.882224+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2019-03-14T10:12:00.556395+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-03-14T10:12:00.556231 #4] INFO -- : [60165716-e021-4054-bf81-0458c5b58fc9] Started GET "/" for 78.108.46.167 at 2019-03-14 10:12:00 +0000
2019-03-14T10:12:00.557797+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-03-14T10:12:00.557694 #4] INFO -- : [60165716-e021-4054-bf81-0458c5b58fc9] Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
2019-03-14T10:12:00.570712+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-03-14T10:12:00.570566 #4] INFO -- : [60165716-e021-4054-bf81-0458c5b58fc9] Rendering pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2019-03-14T10:12:00.575342+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-03-14T10:12:00.575227 #4] INFO -- : [60165716-e021-4054-bf81-0458c5b58fc9] Rendered pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.5ms)
2019-03-14T10:12:00.579304+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-03-14T10:12:00.579206 #4] INFO -- : [60165716-e021-4054-bf81-0458c5b58fc9] Completed 200 OK in 21ms (Views: 10.6ms)
2019-03-14T10:12:00.583809+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=www.teamlink.xyz request_id=60165716-e021-4054-bf81-0458c5b58fc9 fwd="78.108.46.167" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=35ms status=200 bytes=33684 protocol=http
2019-03-14T10:12:00.918795+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/app/Teamlink1-c577c6f42390bafc9a3ae4449c5dc3c5e8b8274499fececbbb2459c1540bdbf5.png" host=www.teamlink.xyz request_id=59432522-abaa-4716-b550-527414017f4f fwd="78.108.46.167" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=http
2019-03-14T10:12:00.913219+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-1a3ba655fd7444ccd9a19c80bc6ac655725ac32db81710749e3edb7b911ab7c8.js" host=www.teamlink.xyz request_id=22360c27-f498-4395-a68f-05550fbc3ca8 fwd="78.108.46.167" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=http
2019-03-14T10:12:00.916510+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/LogoTransparent-34d80e7d46f7a07ab5ac6a4fbd89a1f17e349bffc1ce7042565016d845777dc9.png" host=www.teamlink.xyz request_id=69fed0e0-6216-4b4d-829d-9a63c8b87709 fwd="78.108.46.167" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=http
2019-03-14T10:12:01.055841+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/app/Teamlink3-51ba51be27e4fdcb259cd95556c744f250b39cc3cfe82d8001b8320a50730808.png" host=www.teamlink.xyz request_id=c361c6ed-7ba2-45ff-a735-41624472628c fwd="78.108.46.167" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=http
2019-03-14T10:12:00.911841+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-2f9db7c61263d5cc3ccd205d16cc4007633e699dfc750927a546399d887ca2a6.css" host=www.teamlink.xyz request_id=a57fc598-14ca-411d-962b-8b5a53da8b7a fwd="78.108.46.167" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=http
2019-03-14T10:12:01.053544+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/app/Teamlink2-ad62e650a955481449efcbc557a9a15a42366d8073f0e51668cfd78f82fb183f.png" host=www.teamlink.xyz request_id=e3e954f8-8e2e-4120-b569-eb4019e916eb fwd="78.108.46.167" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=http
2019-03-14T10:12:01.083128+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/app/Teamlink6-1d6a88c95229114a8d83a275495b76a4d9693d76f2cd24a75986b98a6b4591ed.png" host=www.teamlink.xyz request_id=9721d7b0-542f-4014-8918-8ad9c18f7e6a fwd="78.108.46.167" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=http
2019-03-14T10:12:01.079936+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/app/Teamlink5-fbb0407ca4f599915a01679b060b044d7066bd74a54a58cd816fa3923bfa974d.png" host=www.teamlink.xyz request_id=1ef32db7-c99c-40fd-ae55-678b4e6d4ec3 fwd="78.108.46.167" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=http
2019-03-14T10:12:01.071262+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/app/Teamlink4-e3c4bed1d417d2dec279733e24d40880fc59cc6eb83ff8e1bc26987a1443c4e1.png" host=www.teamlink.xyz request_id=5065824a-e6ad-485e-9756-68d5baf61978 fwd="78.108.46.167" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=http
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is normal and is due to link preloading in recent chrome (and may be others). Also this method has been in use for years by many "web accelerator plugins".

Point is in predicting which link user is most probably will click and start loading it in advance so that later it can be opened instantly. Thus when you appear as top result - you'll probably get a request before user clicks the link.

Comment: OK, this is interesting. Do you mean that this only happens when the site appears as top results and not when it it appears with a lower rank?

Comment: @kouroubel haven't tested this, actually prefetch can hit all of the links on page if left for some time, but at least we can assume that link was shown to a user, if request came

Answer (score 1):

maybe try to block Google bot with robots.txt and block access to your site. But it will execlude it from the index and could take some time to process.

Comment: That's OK I would not want to complicate things. I was rather curious to find out why this happens...